# Mixing cells from storyboard and programmatically created cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have collection view in the storyboard. I have a part of cells in storyboard and part of cells I created programmatically. What should I do in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method? Which value should I return? For my programmatically created cells I return size for him. But I don't want copy size from storyboard for cells from storyboard. I mean, I have:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
      return self.viewModels[indexPath.item].viewSize // for programmatically created cells
}
```

And in viewModel class:

```
class ViewModel {
    var viewSize:CGSize = CGSizeMake(50, 50)//for example
}
```

Also, I have cells from storyboard and size of it I setted in storyboard. For example, I have 5 different cells in storyboard and each has different size. Should I do ?

```
 let viewModel = self.viewModels[indexPath.item]
 if viewModel.id == "CELL_1" { return CGSizeMake(10, 10) }
 else if viewModel.id == "CELL_2" { return CGSizeMake(20, 20) }
 //and so on
```

I don't want to make this :(
Do you know solution how I can get size of item from storyboard or create behaviour when this method is not implemented? (I mean, if you don't implement this method then collection view will get size from storyboard)

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate the cell using its reuse ID and call:

```
cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

then access the cell's frame to get it's actual size.

Comment: How I should get cell In the sizeForItemAtPath? If I try get cell through collectionView.deque...withIdentifier then I get crash

Comment: I see, maybe you could move your cells from prototype cells to separate NIB files and load them manually.

Comment: I create library for working with tableView/collectionView. And I don't know how user will use it, unfortunatelly